# how to get user latitude and longitude in a label by clicking uibutton

Tags: ios, swift4

I am trying to get user current location latitude and longitude by using reverse CLgeocoding.but,i think methods doesn't called. i am not getting any result in console at least.If any one helps me to do this,would be great.Thank in advance.

```
import UIKit
import CoreLocation

class ViewController: UIViewController,CLLocationManagerDelegate {

    @IBOutlet weak var lbl2: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var lbl1: UILabel!
    var str1: Double?
    var str2: Double?

    var locationManager:CLLocationManager!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)
       determineMyCurrentLocation()

    }


    func determineMyCurrentLocation() {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        locationManager.delegate = self
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        locationManager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()

        if CLLocationManager.locationServicesEnabled() {
            locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
            //locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
        }
    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(manager.location!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in

            if (error != nil) {
                print("ERROR:" + error!.localizedDescription)

                return
            }

            if (placemarks?.count)! > 0 {
                let pm = placemarks![0] as CLPlacemark
                self.displayLocationInfo(placemark: pm)
            } else {
                print("Error with data")

            }
        })
    }
    func displayLocationInfo(placemark: CLPlacemark) {
        //  self.locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation()

        print(placemark.locality)
        print(placemark.postalCode)
        print(placemark.administrativeArea)
        print(placemark.country)
        print(placemark.location)

    }

    func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didFailWithError error: Error)
    {
        print("Error \(error)")
    }

    @IBAction func currentadd(_ sender: Any) {


    }
```

Comment: you want to get user location latitude and longitude  or  user location address, as well as you want in one time or multiple time

Comment: where you called the `determineMyCurrentLocation`

Comment: in viewwillappear method ,i called that function

Comment: user location address i want to get

Answer (score 0):

First make sure you have added one of the keys in your Info.plist

`NSLocationAlwaysUsageDescription` or `NSLocationWhenInUseUsageDescription`.

Second you need to call `determineMyCurrentLocation` method in your `viewDidLoad` or `viewDidAappear`. You can also call `determineMyCurrentLocation` from any button or event according to your need.

> Edit

One more thing i would like to suggest is you should call `manager.stopUpdatingLocation()` in your `didUpdateLocations` if you don't want to use location service constantly.

**Updated method**

```
func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations: [CLLocation]) {
        if let managerLocation = manager.location{
            CLGeocoder().reverseGeocodeLocation(managerLocation) { (placemarks, error) in
                if let locations = placemarks ,let location = locations.first {
                    self.displayLocationInfo(placemark: location)
                }else if let error = error{
                    print("ERROR:" + error.localizedDescription)
                }
            }
        }
 }
```